# Aggregate query returning multiple rows when I only want one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

this is the original query

```
  SELECT     'MSD-RES-CRUISE' AS QUERYNAME, dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID, SUM(dbo.BOOKINGS.APRICE) AS total, COUNT(dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID) AS TOTAL2 
    FROM         dbo.BOOKINGS INNER JOIN  dbo.TOURS ON dbo.BOOKINGS.TOUR = dbo.TOURS.TOUR INNER JOIN
                  dbo.MAJOR ON dbo.TOURS.MAJOR = dbo.MAJOR.MAJOR 
    WHERE     (dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKED BETWEEN CONVERT(int, Dateadd(day,2, @startdate)) AND CONVERT(int, Dateadd(day,2, @enddate))) AND (dbo.MAJOR.SDESCR = 'Cruises') AND  
                          (dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID = @USER) AND (dbo.MAJOR.DIVISION = 'A') and dbo.BOOKINGS.STATUS <> 'XL' GROUP BY dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID
```

the query i want to join

```
 SELECT     calltimeint, avetimeint
    FROM         dbo.agentdailycalls
    where userid = @user and date1 between @startdate and @enddate
```

where the userids match and the groupname matches query name

this is what i used

```
SELECT     t0.QUERYNAME, t0.USERID, total, TOTAL2, calltimeint, avetimeint 
FROM       (    SELECT     'MSD-RES-CRUISE' AS QUERYNAME, dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID, SUM(dbo.BOOKINGS.APRICE) AS total, COUNT(dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID) AS TOTAL2 
    FROM         dbo.BOOKINGS INNER JOIN  dbo.TOURS ON dbo.BOOKINGS.TOUR = dbo.TOURS.TOUR INNER JOIN
                  dbo.MAJOR ON dbo.TOURS.MAJOR = dbo.MAJOR.MAJOR 
    WHERE     (dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKED BETWEEN CONVERT(int, Dateadd(day,2, @startdate)) AND CONVERT(int, Dateadd(day,2, @enddate))) AND (dbo.MAJOR.SDESCR = 'Cruises') AND  
                          (dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID = @USER) AND (dbo.MAJOR.DIVISION = 'A') and dbo.BOOKINGS.STATUS <> 'XL' GROUP BY dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID 
) t0 
INNER JOIN (   SELECT     sum(calltimeint) as calltimeint, sum(avetimeint) as avetimeint , userid
    FROM         dbo.agentdailycalls
    where userid = @user and date1 between @startdate and @enddate and GroupName = 'MSD-RES-CRUISE'
 group by userid
) t1         ON t1.userId = t0.USERID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a JOIN on the two queries:

```
SELECT     QUERYNAME, USERID, total, TOTAL2, calltimeint, avetimeint
FROM       ('MSD-RES-CRUISE' ... GROUP BY abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID) t0
INNER JOIN (SELECT userid, groupname, calltimeint, avetimeint ... and @enddate) t1
        ON t1.userId = t0.USERID AND t01.groupname = t0.QUERYNAME
```

---

**OLD ANSWER, based on a previous version of the question**

Instead of selecting `calltimeint` and `avetimeint` it looks like you want to select the SUM of each of those columns, and remove them from the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT     ... SUM(dbo.agentdailycalls.calltimeint), SUM(dbo.agentdailycalls.avetimeint)
FROM       dbo.BOOKINGS INNER JOIN ...
GROUP BY   dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID
```

Adding them to the `GROUP BY` means you want a row for every different combination of these values.  So, `GROUP BY userid, calltimeint, avetimeint` means "return one row for every different combination of userid, call time, and average time".

What you really meant (presumably) is "return one row for each user", so you should only have `userid` in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @whatsup Where should "31548.330000" and "8" come from?  Do you want the minimum values (not the SUM as your original query shows"?

Comment: before i started i began adding the call data such as the calltimeint and avetimeint, i was only gathering the sales data which was verified to be 8 and 31548.33 so for some reason the call data is gathering this information for each row and then adding it

Comment: @whatsup if you're seeing data that's way too high, it's probably because you're joining on rows multiple times

Comment: ill post my original query up top it returns a single row of a sum of all the sales data, then based on the queryname column should match to the dbo.agentdailcalls.userid and dbo.agentdailcalls.groupname and show the avetimeint and calltimeint

Comment: thanks ill take a look sorry this has been troubling me for hours

Comment: alright i cleared the mess up top and just seperated the two queries i want to join together

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
SELECT     'MSD-RES-CRUISE' AS QUERYNAME
        , abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID
            , SUM(tt.calltime)
            , SUM(tt.aveTimeint)
        , SUM(abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS.APRICE) AS total
        , COUNT(abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID) AS TOTAL2 
FROM         abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS 
INNER JOIN  abcfiles.dbo.TOURS 
            ON abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS.TOUR = abcfiles.dbo.TOURS.TOUR 
INNER JOIN  abcfiles.dbo.MAJOR 
            ON abcfiles.dbo.TOURS.MAJOR = abcfiles.dbo.MAJOR.MAJOR
INNER JOIN         (SELECT 
                     calltime
               , aveTimeint
            FROM 
                    dbo.agentdailycalls adc
            ) tt 
                     ON tt.userid = abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINDS.USERID 
                    AND tt.date1 BETWEEN @startdate AND @endDate***                         
WHERE     (abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKED BETWEEN CONVERT(int, Dateadd(day,2, @startdate)) AND CONVERT(int, Dateadd(day,2, @enddate))) 
AND (abcfiles.dbo.MAJOR.SDESCR = 'Cruises') 
AND  (abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID = @USER) 
AND (abcfiles.dbo.MAJOR.DIVISION = 'A') 
and abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS.STATUS <> 'XL' 
GROUP BY abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID
```

Comment: No i just was really slow in getting it up on the site. so i dont think it actually is any different. APART from i Am SUMMING the CalTime and AVeTimeInt per user.